# Changing UI color in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, colors

I'm aware of color themes for Eclipse: I've used it to change most of the editor colors, and that's great.

But that wasn't enough, there's still too much white. How to change it? (It hurts my eyes.)

I've searched in the preferences (both using Eclipse itself and editing the files) for instances of white (255,255,255) and changed them all. Looks like I'm missing something.

Comment: bonus track: http://www.imagebanana.com/view/elg9jzjm/withouteclipse.png

Comment: Simple solution: Switch on the light, or, if you have windows in your office, work during day time. ;-)

Comment: ahahah no, sorry, white areas really hurt me much, there can't be workarounds.

Comment: I didn't really have to use eclipse: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/other-ide.html

as far as I'm concerned, problem dodged

Answer (score 7):

Each time you see white or gray color, this is more than likely related to **OS system colors**.

In other word, to truly have an Eclipse full dark theme, you need first to have a dark theme for your OS, and then your Eclipse will follow.

Here is an example on a Windows7, modifying just one parameter:

[alt text http://img92.imageshack.us/img92/5053/eclipsered.png](http://img92.imageshack.us/img92/5053/eclipsered.png)

Comment: Unfortunately the widget colors in OS X are not too customizable, e.g. in Snow Leopard there are just 2 built-in color schemes.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not the answer you're looking for, but the IntelliJ community edition is an excellent free IDE and is very easy to use. The background colours can be set and changed to many colours. There are also a number of free plugins which can customize backgrounds and the look and feel. Well worth a look if you don't find exactly what you're looking for with Eclipse.

Comment: I have to use eclipse because it has integrated stuff for Android :/

I'm already missing textmate so much...

Answer (score 2):

I see you're on the Mac - the easiest thing to do would go to System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Seeing -> Display -> "White on Black". It will invert everything on your screen though, I don't know, if you'd like that?

Answer (score 2):

You can try these steps:

1. Find the path: `~/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_*.*.****.v********-****/css/e4_basestyle.css`;
2. Use a text editor (example: Sublime Text 3) to open `e4_basestyle.css` if you used default theme config;
3. Append this code and save

```
#org-eclipse-jdt-ui-PackageExplorer Tree,
#org-eclipse-ui-navigator-ProjectExplorer Tree {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: "DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline";
  background-color: RGB(223,238,223);
},
#org-eclipse-ui-views-ContentOutline Tree,
#PerspectiveSwitcher ToolBar {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: "DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline";
  background-color: RGB(223,238,223);
}
```

Restart Eclipse. It is like this: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pzcpb.png)

Answer (score 1):

***YES, THERE IS A WAY TO DO IT***

You will need to configure 3 things in order to get your dark UI.

**1) Java Editor Colors**
This is the source code edition area. You can use http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/ for the editor part, though those colors can be manually edited by default.

**2) Eclipse UI**
The UI colors can be edited with the addin *Chrome Theme* which can be found in the eclipse market place or in the following link  https://github.com/jeeeyul/eclipse-themes/. If you want a dark theme just edit away until you find the colors that suit you.

**3) Final touches**
After doing the previous steps, some colors will still match the OS colors. To darken what's left, just get the pre-baked Dark Juno theme from https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-ui-themes. Download the zip file and unzip it into your *dropins* folder (which is located in your eclipse folder). If the *dropins* folder doesn't exist, just create it.

Restart eclipse and you are set.