# eclipse 3.5: servers panel, the names of servers are in white color, so i want to change back to black

Tags: eclipse

eclipse: servers panel, the names of servers are in white color, so i want to change back to black. how do i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends of the nature of the window you are talking about, but if there is no apparent preference for changing its background, then it is most probably a **system color**.

See [Changing UI color in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439007/changing-ui-color-in-eclipse/2439062#2439062).

Comment: i changed the color of the text to white.. but i dont remember where is the setting..