# Themes for Dart Editor

Tags: dart, dart-editor

Right now, the white background is killing my eyes, as it's a *looong* dark night.
Is it possible to change the theme (to something darker) from the Dart Editor (v 0.1)? What about picking a background colour and syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and I have just verified this quickfix for a darker background on the Dart Editor `Version 0.1.0.201204042313`:

1. Close the Dart Editor
2. Open with your favorite editor the file: `<DART-INSTALL-DIR>\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs`
3. Change the content

*from:*

```
 #Fri Apr 06 20:28:37 EST 2012
 eclipse.preferences.version=1
 overviewRuler_migration=migrated_3.1
```

*to:*

```
#Fri Apr 06 20:28:38 EST 2012
AbstractTextEditor.Color.Background.SystemDefault=false
AbstractTextEditor.Color.Background=208,208,223
eclipse.preferences.version=1
overviewRuler_migration=migrated_3.1
```

Start your Dart Editor and the background should look like: [image]

You may create a "complete theme" simply adding more properties to the `org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs` and `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs` files.

I strongly suggest you to have a look inside the "Eclipse Preferences (EPF)" sample files of the project http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/

I haven't tried yet but in theory you could manually install the plugin [Eclipse Color Theme](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-color-theme).

---

**Update 06-Dec-2012**

The new `Dart Editor Build 0.2.7.1_r15699` [supports theming](http://news.dartlang.org/2012/12/new-dart-editor-build-0271r15699.html) for both editor and panels. This "trick" is not needed anymore, please customize your theme using `Preferences --> Visual Theme`
[image]

Comment: yeah it works. now we need only for the console and left project windows too :)

Comment: Have you seen this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2439062/81444 ? I'm sure there should be another way to achieve it...

Answer (score 2):

Hannes Rammer built an open source tool for this

- https://github.com/HannesRammer/Rainbow (GitHub)
- http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/rainbow

also available online at 
https://rainbow-dart.appspot.com/

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible. It has been filed as an issue: http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=293&q=themes&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Area%20Owner%20Summary