# How to fix Dart hints background color

Tags: autocomplete, background, ide, dart, hint

I just installed Dart, and the hints(of the autocomplete feature) had black text over dark grey background, nearly unredeable.
How can I fix this?
I already tried to change the theme of the IDE but that  didn't work.

Check the image to see what I'm talking about:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7nFJ.png

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why changing the theme shouldn't help.
Beside from that you can take a look at [Themes for Dart Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036358) (links to a tools to customize the colors)